# Performance with Castle Windsor Interceptors

Tags: castle-windsor, aop, castle, interceptor

As suggested by many, logging is better managed through AOP, and in my case, using Castle Windsor interceptors.

I am currently developing a web app and we just added an interceptor to log every method that is called (the methods are tagged by a custom attribute therefore I can choose the method I want to log).  When I test the web app the performance is awful.  Sometimes it might take up to 10 seconds for a page to render.  Without the interceptor the pages load instantly.

Are there any tips when adding interceptors and performance or is it actually this slow?

Comment: Proper implementation of logging interceptors has no noticeable impact on performance. Post your code.

Comment: thanks...i found the issue and it has to do with NH Profiler

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.  I executed my test cases and the performance difference was minor with the interceptors enabled.  I checked my log4net configuration and I saw that I had NH Profiler enabled.  I removed the profiler and the performance sky rocketed.  It seems that there is something strange going on when the profiler is working.

Just to make sure my case is fine, I enabled ATM with profiler on/off.  When the profiler was on the performance degradation was HUGE.  When the profiler was off everything was fine.